# Cant figure out a way to animate after the given 5 seconds waiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to get a loading page for my site up and running, although its not loading actually it just waits at least 5 seconds before it disappears.

Everything works fine except that I want the given ID that disappears do so with an animation. (For example swiping up out of the screen)

Im still very new to jQuery and Javascript, and Im trying to learn with this along the way.

I tried various methods I know but none of them actually worked with the code i have already. It either doesnt run at all or just doesnt show any kind of animation

As said above: I tried various fade in and outs just to see where the problem is but no animation actually works. Just trying to figuire out what im doing wrong so I can learn from it.

heres some code:

```js
function onReady(callback) {
var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 5000);
function checkReady() {
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
window.clearInterval(intervalID);
callback.call(this);
}
}
}
function show(id, value) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
}
onReady(function () {
show('page', true).fadeIn(6000);
show('loading', false).fadeOut(6000);
});
```

Ive tried adding servaeral animations but they either dont show or the whole code starts breaking.

As mentioned I am new to jQuery and Javascript so Im trying to learn. Please give me something I can learn with along the way.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried various fade in and outs just to see where the problem is but no animation actually works.

The provided code seems to be a mix of JavaScript and jQuery techniques which are not quite lining up. As your primary objective is animation and you are learning, I suggest use only jQuery at first.

Here is a snippet that performs the animation using jQuery which you should recognize by the use of the jQuery alias `$`.

1. It uses the jQuery `ready` event to make sure the page loads first
2. It uses the jQuery `delay` function to wait 5 seconds
3. It uses the jQuery `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions for the animation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".loading").delay(5000).fadeOut();
  $(".page").delay(5000).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.loading {
  position: absolute;
}

.page {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loading">Loading...</div>
<div class="page">Welcome</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I kind of still need to learn a lot of jQuery, never knew it could look that easy :)